# Free $\mathbb{Z}$ module question

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Is $M=\left\{\frac{a}{2^n}| a \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module?  I am struggling with free modules and am not sure how I would check this?  I know that the basis cannot be finite from another problem I have worked before.  However, I am not sure about the infinite basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already know that a basis, if one existed, would have to be infinite, you can complete the proof by noting that your group doesn't contain even two (let alone infinitely many) linearly independent elements.

Answer (score 8):

Suppose $A$ is a free $\Bbb{Z}$-module, and $b$ is an element of a basis. Then there is no element $a\in A$ such that $2a=b$, since otherwise $b$ would have two different representations in terms of basis elements. Thus in your $M$ there is nothing that could possibly be a basis element, so there is no basis.

Comment: But you did not assume $a$ or $2$ was a basis element so why is your second sentence valid?

Comment: $2$ isn't an element of the module at all, it's an element of $\Bbb{Z}$. And $a$ need not be a basis element, but it is a linear combination of basis elements.

Comment: of course on both points.